# rspec controller subject instance_variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a controller and tests it through rspec:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  subject { get :index }

  it { expect(subject).to render_template(:index) }
```

My controller generates instance variables passed to views, smth. like that:

```
@specifications = current_user.specifications
```

How can I test that controller pass instance variables correct?

Something like that:

```
it { expect(subject).assign(:contractors).to match_array(my_array) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `controller` helper test method

```
describe TetsController do
  let(:user) { build_stubbed :user }

  before do
    controller.stub authenticate_user!: true,
      current_user: user
  end

  describe 'GET index' do
    let(:plans) { double :plans }

    before do
      expect(Plan).to receive(:all).and_return(plans)
    end

    it 'response success' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it 'assign plans' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:plans)).to eq plans
    end
  end
end
```

Small example. `controller` has instance variable `@plans`. It's accessed as `assigns(:plans)`

Comment: Can you explain and show full code? I tried to pass `controller` into my code, but with no success.

Comment: I know about this version of code. But how can I avoid multiline for just 1 loc with `expect(subject)` ?